# missing unicode character

Tags: keyboard, internationalization, unicode

I am searching the Unicode character &#x23FB in Apple's character table. I cannot find it, even though it has been introduced in Unicode 9. I seached the whole unicode tables on the mac.

The character looks like the power button on the Mac. When I copy it from the web, it is being replaced by a question mark.

Any ideas on how to use this? I thought unicode was accessible on all devices.

Answer (score 1):

To use any unicode character not provided by Apple in MacOS/iOS, you just have to install a font which does include it.  [This page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23fb/fontsupport.htm) gives you a couple.

Answer (score 0):

This Unicode character is not available on iOS/macOS as of iOS 11.1 beta 2 and macOS 10.13.2 beta.

Comment: The question is how to make it available.

Answer (score 0):

⏻ is available in MacOS 12.6 using Unicode Hex Input keyboard layout.